# Minimum-perimeter triangle embedded inside a given triangle

Tags: geometry, optimization

A friend gave me this problem but I have no idea how to approach it.

Suppose you are given a triangle $ABC$. Pick points $P, Q$ and $R$ on $BC, CA$ and $AB$ such that the perimeter of the triangle $PQR$ ($PQ+QR+RQ$) is minimized.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming ABC is acute angled, this is [Fagnano's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagnano%27s_problem), and has an [elegant solution using reflection](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Fagnano.shtml#Schwartz). More proofs : [Cut the Knot page on Fagnano's problem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Fagnano.shtml).

For acute angled triangles, it is the orthic triangle (whose vertices are the feet of the perpendicular from the vertices to the opposite sides).

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 (Page 203) and Problem 7 (Page 207) from the section on Geometry Gems in the book "Challenges and Thrills of Pre college Mathematics" answers your question. The google books link is [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=SnvBeodeTDcC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Geometric%20Gems&f=false).

( This was one of the beautiful constructions I remember having seen while preparing for my olympiad, years back :))

Comment: Thanks for pointing to what seems to be a very interesting book.